# OrientDB,linux,java api, cannot,open,storage

Tags: java, orientdb

I am trying to use the java api to create a new database and graph instance, the path exists but I keep getting the error "cannot open the storage ' because it does not exist in path.

It does, the directory exists. I tried creating an empty file but I still see the message, here is the code:

```
OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("plocal:/home/test/orientDB/testDB").setupPool(1,10);

OrientGraph graph = factory.getTx();
```

I saw on an earlier post that the graph api is not supported in PHP, but it should be in Java as that is the native api for orientDB and matches the documentation on github

Answer (score 2):

You should create the database before. You can use the console (see [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Console-Command-Create-Database.html#console---create-database)) for that. And then you can create the factory as described [here](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Graph-Database-Tinkerpop.html#use-the-factory).